# Moodle removes all notifications on test results page

Tags: php, moodle

**Moodle version**: v3.11, **platform**: Windows 10, **theme**: classic

Good afternoon, I need to display some html code on a page displaying test results. But apparently, Moodle overwrites the page, because even the following code, which works on every page:

```php
function local_adaptive_quiz_before_footer(){
    error_log('local_adaptive_quiz_before_footer worked');
    \core\notification::add('The Local adaptive quiz plugin has been launched! v2', \core\output\notification::NOTIFY_SUCCESS);
}
```

Does not appear on the test result page.

But with slow loading you can see how the notification appears for a second, and then when the page fully loads it disappears.

**Final question:**
How can I make the notification and my code from the plugin work on the page displaying the test results?

So far I have only tried to rummage through the course or test settings, but I have not found any items on the topic “Delete other content on the page,” I assume that it is necessary to change the source code of the quiz module

Comment: You should never touch any core code, if you touch the quiz module code you'll have huge trouble for update and you'll never now what side trouble may arise.
Can you explain how you generate your page ? 
Do you use the OUTPUT and PAGE global ? Do you also use a mustache template ?

Comment: I just use it echo '<h1>Output text</h1>';